# Matching elements where all fields satisfy a given condition

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection 'objects', which have a list field 'elements', which, on the other hand, 
have another list field 'items', which, in turn, can be of two kinds 'a' or 'b' as follows:

```
use test;

db.objects.insert({
  "_id" : "e81d80ffae684cfd9147bc4017c42b9a",
  "elements" : [{
      "items" : [
          {"id" : "3632407fca17f4a1307c96659ebe32762ffe5d22", "kind" : "a"},
          {"id" : "3632407fca17f4a1307c96659ebe32762ffe5d22", "kind" : "b"}
      ]
  }]
})

db.objects.insert({
  "_id" : "1e0fd210530d4580af95b8eb7f2b38df",
  "elements" : [ 
        {
            "items" : [
                {"id" : "27d6fabba14a4473b7786258127ec68b", "kind" : "a"},
                {"id" : "6c9c223391ec46078ef02e00683fe167", "kind" : "b"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "items" : [
                {"id" : "3fd8631ab15e46c7982093bcb08c868d", "kind" : "a"}
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

I need to perform a query that matches for all objects where any element have all it items 
of kind different than 'b'.

Is it possible to do through a Mongo query without creating a Javascript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform that query using `$elemMatch` and `$ne`:

```js
db.objects.find({
    elements: {$elemMatch: {'items.kind': {$ne: 'b'}}}
})
```

That will find docs that have at least one `elements` element where there are no `items` array elements where `kind` is `'b'`.

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : "1e0fd210530d4580af95b8eb7f2b38df",
    "elements" : [ 
        {
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "27d6fabba14a4473b7786258127ec68b",
                    "kind" : "a"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "6c9c223391ec46078ef02e00683fe167",
                    "kind" : "b"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "3fd8631ab15e46c7982093bcb08c868d",
                    "kind" : "a"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With JS

```
db.objects.find(
    {
      '$where': 'this.elements.map(function(element){return element.items.every(function(item){return item.kind !== "b"})}).indexOf(true) >= 0'
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care for the ids you can use an aggregation pipeline:

```
> db.objects.aggregate(
...   {$unwind: "$elements"}, 
...   {$project: {_id:1, item_id:"$elements.items.id", kind: "$elements.items.kind"}},
...   {$match: {kind: {$ne: "b"}}}
... )
```

After that you could fetch the documents with an `$in` query. Maybe using `$elemMatch` is faster.